# Late inheritance, enforce subclass behavior in the future

Tags: object-oriented, python, inheritance, dynamic-inheritance

A super class `Transaction` has two subclasses `TransactionA` and `TransactionB`. A `Transaction` is composed of multiple events that occur in time for a specific key (a file, a person, etc.). Depending on events, some transactions have to be discarded.

A concrete example with a file "key" would look like:

- `TransactionA` represents a set of file events whereas the file is being read, let's call it `TransactionRead`
- `TransactionB` is a set of file events for the file being written, calling it `TransactionWrite`

A same file can be read or write at any given time.

An event list would look like this (very simplified):

1. Open FileA
2. Open FileB
3. Create FileB
4. Read FileA
5. Write FileB
6. EOF FileA
7. Read FileB
8. EOF FileB

At step 1 and 2, the transaction is yet to be known, we have needed information (a timestamp, a file name, a username, etc.) but we don't know yet if it's a `TransactionRead` or `TransactionWrite`.

My rational would be to create a class `Transaction` that holds enough services to analyze events and a method `who_i_am` that returns `READ` or `WRITE` if the pattern fits (Ex.: Open -> Read -> EOF for a read transaction), `None` if no pattern found.

At some point the transaction type will be known and I think it would be a good approach to morph `Transaction` into a `TransactionRead`. I'm coding in Python atm, but I've never heard of a concept like this. Is it bad, why? Do languages provide tools for late inheritance?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Prefer *early* composition over *late* inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance):

- The class of an object has to be known at creation, and most languages do not allow to change it later.  So, if you create a transaction, it ***IS*** a `Transaction` (inheritance);
- If the object has to change afterwards, it must be via its state:  the transaction may ***HAVE*** some properties/behaviors depending on the history of events that affected it (composition);
- Several known design patterns can help.  In your case, I could very well imagine :

  - **[state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)**:  `Transaction` starts with a `TransactionUndetermined` state, then gets either a `TransactionRead` or `TransactionWrite` state, and then finally a `TransactionClosed` state, depending on the events encountered. The interface exposed would be the same for all the states, but the behavior could change dynamically.
  - **[decorator pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html)**: a `TransactionRead` and `TransactionWrite` decorator could enrich the `Transaction` with additional responsibilities/behaviors/properties.  The context that uses the Transaction would then have to use the decorator instead of the original object.  All the decorators would implement the same base behavior (e.g. forwarding function calls to the original object), but each decorator can expose its own interface for the added responsibilities.